# Class syntax equivalent of adding a shared value to a prototype?

Tags: javascript

Say I have this class

```
class banana {
    constructor(weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }
}

banana.prototype.type = "fruit";
```

So different bananas have different weights but all bananas are fruits hence I want to add the "type = fruit" to the prototype instead of the instances.

I don't like to have to do this after the class declaration ends though, it would be neater for me to keep methods and prototype variables close together by what they are for, for readability.

Is there syntax to do this inside the class brackets? Sorta like

```
class banana {
    type = "fruit" <- doesn't work of course

    constructor(weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried this.type = "fruit" inside the constructor? Then each banana has the type "fruit"

Comment: Will work soon. It is currently in an [upcoming proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: I hope the private field proposal doesn't go through, i prefer the TypeScript approach

Comment: @pavlo what?? Its the same in typescript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define a small helper function:

```
const Type = prototype => Object.assign(function(){}, {prototype});
```

And then extend it:

```
class Test extends Type({some:"prop"}) {
  constructor(){
   super();
   //...
  }
  //...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Inside a class statement, only methods are allowed, no assignments.
So if you want to set the type you will have to do it in the constructor, like this:

```
class banana {

    constructor(weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
        this.type = "fruit";
    }
}
```

If you don't want to do thiy then you could also define your constant as a function but that feels a bit hacky to me:

```
class banana {

    constructor(weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    static type() {return "fruit";}
}
```

Comment: why not static? it is a constant

Comment: Cause there is no `static` keyword in javaacript

Comment: [are you sure?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static)

Comment: Oh wow. Im working with classes since two years and never noticed. Im so sorry...

Answer (score 0):

you can set it in the constructor:

```
class Banana {
  constructor() {
    this.type = 'fruit';
  }
}
```

or you could have a Fruit class, of which Banana is a subclass:

```
class Fruit {
  constructor() {
    this.type = 'fruit';
  }
}

class Banana extends Fruit {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
}
```

or, if you're using Babel, you can add the [transform-class-properties plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/):

```
class Banana {
  type = 'fruit';
}

// .babelrc
{
  "plugins": [[
    "transform-class-properties"
  ]]
}
```

Comment: this is different though, it adds the type to the constructed object, not the prototype.